# Android app does not launch app permissions

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

I have an android app made in cordova (just cordova not the ionic one). The app has an iframe an inside there are PDF to download, but I'm unable to do it.

I read somewhere that it was needed to modify the config XML and the android manifest to add the Read and Write Storage permissions.

I also tried withj cordova file permission plugin but nothing changed.

With both files modified, I tested the app but the permission are launched in the browser version. In the android one the app does not detect the permission request and when I tried to download a PDF nothing happens.

This is the same if the Storage permission is activated inside the settings of the app.

Here's my Android manifest

`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="40000" android:versionName="4.0.0" package="com.something" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
</manifest>`
```

And my config.xml

`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.something" version="4.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Somename</name>
    <description>
        Soemthing
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
        <config-file after="uses-permission" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
</widget>`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the permissions in the config.xml no longer work since the last versions of android.

### You can use this plugin : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

It gives you the ability to check whether or not the user has refused the authorization and to ask again.

### Example usage

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalStorageAuthorizationStatus(function(status){
    if(status === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){
        console.log("External storage use is authorized");
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Comment: Well, the thing is that the user cannout accept or decline the permissions request, because when the app is installed it does not detect any special permission.

Comment: yes, this is the case with the new versions of android.
Now the user must give his consent during the use of the app.

Comment: This plugin is not working on the app. Could it be that there's something blocking plugins execution?